# Kind of pyramid numbers pattern exercise

Tags: python, design-patterns, numbers

Can you help to simplify this code and make it more efficient? Mine seems like it's not the best version; what can I improve?

```
     1
    232
   34543
  4567654
 567898765
678901109876
```

This is the code I made:

```
c = -1

for y in range(1, 7):
    print()
    print((6-y) * " ", end="")
    c += 1

    for x in range(1, y+1):
        print(y%10, end="")
        y += 1

    while y - c > 2:
        print(y-2, end="")
        y -= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm guessing that you didn't really want to print that **y** value of 10; that you really wanted the base-10 reduction to 0.  Note that you have an extra character in the pyramid base.

Do *not* change the value of a loop parameter while you're inside the loop.  Specifically, don't change y within the **for y** loop.

Get rid of **c**; you can derive it from the other values.

For flexibility, make your upper limit a parameter: you have two constants (6 and 7) that depend on one concept (row limit).

Here's my version:

```
row_limit = 7

for y in range(1, row_limit):
    print()
    print((row_limit-y-1) * " ", end="")

    for x in range(y, 2*y):
        print(x%10, end="")

    for x in range(2*(y-1), y-1, -1):
        print(x%10, end="")

print()
```

Output:

```
     1
    232
   34543
  4567654
 567898765
67890109876
```

---

If you really want to push things, you can shorten the loops with string concatenation and comprehension, but it's likely harder to read for you.

```
for y in range(1, row_limit):
    print()
    print((row_limit-y-1) * " " + ''.join([str(x%10) for x in range(y, 2*y)]) + \
              ''.join([str(x%10) for x in range(2*(y-1), y-1, -1)]), end="")

print()
```

Each of the loops is turned into a list comprehension, such as:

```
[str(x%10) for x in range(y, 2*y)]
```

Then, this list of characters is joined with no interstitial character; this forms half of the row.  The second half of the row is the other loop (counting down).  In front of all this, I concatenate the proper number of spaces.

Frankly, I prefer my first form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation.

**Python 2**:

```
def print_triangle(n):
    for row_num in xrange(1, n + 1):
        numbers = [str(num % 10) for num in xrange(row_num, 2 * row_num)]
        num_string = ''.join(numbers + list(reversed(numbers))[1:])
        print '{}{}'.format(' ' * (n - row_num), num_string)
```

**Python 3**:

```
def print_triangle(n):
    for row_num in range(1, n + 1):
        numbers = [str(num % 10) for num in range(row_num, 2 * row_num)]
        num_string = ''.join(numbers + list(reversed(numbers))[1:])
        print('{}{}'.format(' ' * (n - row_num), num_string))
```

**Input**:

```
print_triangle(5)
print_triangle(6)
print_triangle(7)
```

**Output**:

```
    1
   232
  34543
 4567654
567898765
     1
    232
   34543
  4567654
 567898765
67890109876
      1
     232
    34543
   4567654
  567898765
 67890109876
7890123210987
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
i = 1
while i <= n:
    j = 1
    spaces = 1
    p = i
while spaces <= n - i:
    print (" ", end ="")
    spaces += 1
while j <= i:
    print(p, end = "")
    j += 1
    p += 1
p -= 2
while p >= i:
    print(p, end = "")
    p -= 1
print()
i += 1
```

Comment: Please add more details supporting you answer. Why do you think this is more efficient than OP's code. Check this link on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).